# Нужно добавить текст к созданным с помощью js блокам

Tags: javascript, html, css

Нужно, что бы когда появлялся блок, вместе с ним появлялся и тег `p` с текстом:

Автор: (введённый текст)
Комментарий: (введённый текст)

```js
function onClick() {
    var container = document.getElementById("container");
    var textarea1 = document.getElementById("textarea1");
    var text1 = document.getElementById("text1");

    var len = container.querySelectorAll('.divA').length;
   if(len >= 3){ return; }
  
    var div1 = document.createElement("div");
    div1.className = "div1";
    div1.innerHTML = text1.value;
  
    var div2 = document.createElement("div");
    div2.className = "div2";
    div2.innerHTML = textarea1.value;
  
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.className = "divA";
    div.appendChild(div1);
    div.appendChild(div2);
  
    container.appendChild(div);
}
```

```css
.div{
 width: 30vw;
 height: 30vh;
 background-color: white;
 display: block;
}
.divA {
    background-color: #eaeaea;
 border: 1px solid black;
 margin: 30px;
 width: 75vw;
 height: 20vh;
 display: block;
}
.div1 {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
.div2 {
    background-color: #ddf;
}
.margin{
 margin-left: 20px;
 margin-top: 20px;
}
#coms{
 background-color: white;
 width: 80vw;
 height: 60vh;
 margin-top: 2%;
 margin-left: 10%;
 border: 1px solid black;
 margin-bottom: 2vh;
}
input{
 height: 30px;
 width: 76vw;
}
textarea{
 width: 76vw;
 height: 30vh;
}
button{
 display: inline-block;
 width: 10vw;
 height: 5vh;
 float: right;
 margin-top: 20px;
 margin-right: 50px;
}
#p_coms{
 margin-top: 10px;
 font-size: 26px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#container{
 background-color: white;
 width: 80vw;
 height: 75vh;
 margin-top:;
 margin-left: 10%;
 border: 1px solid black;
 margin-bottom: 10vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="coms">
 <p class="margin" id="p_coms">Введите ваше имя:</p>
 <input type="text" id="text1"/>
 <br>
 <p class="margin" id="p_coms">Введите вашь комментарий:</p>
 <textarea id="textarea1" cols="40" rows="3"></textarea>
 <br>
 <button onclick="onClick()">Отправить</button>
</div>
<div id="coment">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Насколько понял, настолько и сделал

```js
function onClick() {
    var container = document.getElementById("container");
    var textarea1 = document.getElementById("textarea1");
    var text1 = document.getElementById("text1");

    var len = container.querySelectorAll('.divA').length;
   if(len >= 3){ return; }
  
    var div1 = document.createElement("div"),
      p1 = document.createElement("p");
    div1.className = "div1";
    p1.innerHTML = "Автор: "+text1.value;
    div1.prepend(p1);
    
  
    var div2 = document.createElement("div"),
      p2 = document.createElement("p");
    div2.className = "div2";
    p2.innerHTML = "Комментарий: " + textarea1.value;
    div2.prepend(p2);
  
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.className = "divA";
    div.appendChild(div1);
    div.appendChild(div2);
  
    container.appendChild(div);
}
```

```css
.div{
 width: 30vw;
 height: 30vh;
 background-color: white;
 display: block;
}
.divA {
    background-color: #eaeaea;
 border: 1px solid black;
 margin: 30px;
 width: 75vw;
 height: 20vh;
 display: block;
}
.div1 {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
.div2 {
    background-color: #ddf;
}
.margin{
 margin-left: 20px;
 margin-top: 20px;
}
#coms{
 background-color: white;
 width: 80vw;
 height: 60vh;
 margin-top: 2%;
 margin-left: 10%;
 border: 1px solid black;
 margin-bottom: 2vh;
}
input{
 height: 30px;
 width: 76vw;
}
textarea{
 width: 76vw;
 height: 30vh;
}
button{
 display: inline-block;
 width: 10vw;
 height: 5vh;
 float: right;
 margin-top: 20px;
 margin-right: 50px;
}
#p_coms{
 margin-top: 10px;
 font-size: 26px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#container{
 background-color: white;
 width: 80vw;
 height: 75vh;
 margin-top:;
 margin-left: 10%;
 border: 1px solid black;
 margin-bottom: 10vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="coms">
 <p class="margin" id="p_coms">Введите ваше имя:</p>
 <input type="text" id="text1"/>
 <br>
 <p class="margin" id="p_coms">Введите вашь комментарий:</p>
 <textarea id="textarea1" cols="40" rows="3"></textarea>
 <br>
 <button onclick="onClick()">Отправить</button>
</div>
<div id="container">

</div>
<script>
function onClick() {
    var container = document.getElementById("container");
    var textarea1 = document.getElementById("textarea1");
    var text1 = document.getElementById("text1");

    var len = container.querySelectorAll('.divA').length;
   if(len >= 3){ return; }
  
    var div1 = document.createElement("div"),
      p1 = document.createElement("p");
    div1.className = "div1";
    div1.innerHTML = "Автор: "+text1.value;
    
  
    var div2 = document.createElement("div"),
      p2 = document.createElement("p");
    div2.className = "div2";
    div2.innerHTML = "Комментарий: " + textarea1.value;
  
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.className = "divA";
    div.appendChild(div1);
    div.appendChild(div2);
  
    container.appendChild(div);
}
</script>
```