# Добавить текст к созданным с помощью js блокам

Tags: javascript, html

Нужно что бы когда появлялся блок вместе с ним появлялся и тег `пи` с текстом:

> Автор: (введённый текст)
>
> Комментарий: (введённый текст)

```js
function onClick() {
  var container = document.getElementById("container");
  var textarea1 = document.getElementById("textarea1");
  var text1 = document.getElementById("text1");

  var len = container.querySelectorAll('.divA').length;
  if (len >= 3) {
    return;
  }

  var div1 = document.createElement("div");
  var p1 = document.createElement("p");
  div1.className = "div1";
  p1.className = "p1";
  p1.innerHTML = "Комментарий:";
  div1.innerHTML = text1.value;

  var div2 = document.createElement("div");
  div2.className = "div2";
  div2.innerHTML = textarea1.value;

  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.className = "divA";
  div.appendChild(div1);
  div.appendChild(div2);

  container.appendChild(div);
}
```

```html
<div id="coms">
  <p class="margin" id="p_coms">Введите ваше имя:</p>
  <input type="text" id="text1" />
  <br>
  <p class="margin" id="p_coms">Введите ваш комментарий:</p>
  <textarea id="textarea1" cols="40" rows="3"></textarea>
  <br>
  <button onclick="onClick();">Отправить</button>
</div>
<div id="container">

</div>
```

Comment: зачем вам нужно сделать это задание, если вы не шарите в `js`?

Comment: хороший вопрос, но я прошу помощи и если можете помогите.

Comment: Не надо дублировать вопросы. Ни к чему хорошему это не приведет

Comment: раз вопрос хороший, то надо на него ответить. Еще раз *зачем вам нужно сделать это задание, если вы не шарите в js*

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Нужно добавить текст к созданным с помощью js блокам](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1037827/%d0%9d%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82-%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-js-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const form = document.querySelector('form');

form.addEventListener('submit', createCommentary);

function createCommentary(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  const section = document.querySelector('section');
  const nameInput = document.querySelector('#name');
  const commentInput = document.querySelector('#comment');
  
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = `
    <p>Автор: ${nameInput.value}</p>
    <p>Комментарий: ${commentInput.value}</p>
  `
  section.append(div);
}
```

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<form>

  <div class="row">
    <label for="name">Введите ваше имя:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name">
  </div>
  
  <div class="row">
    <label for="comment">Введите вашь комментарий:</label>
    <textarea id="comment"></textarea>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row">
    <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
  </div>
  
</form>

<section></section>
```